# How to convert int to char*?

Tags: c++, constructor, char, type-conversion

My problem is that I don't know how to convert int value to char array `char* m_value`. I tried to use itoa but it doesn't work. `itoa(m_val, m_wartosc, 10);` Maybe there is some other function to do this ?

**Main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LargeNumber l1;
    LargeNumber l3(172839); //how to convert this int to char*

    return 0;
}
```

**LargeNumber.h**

```
    class LargeNumber{

            public:

                LargeNumber()
                { 
                    m_array = "0"; //zero for no arg.
                }
                LargeNumber(int val):m_val(val)
                {
                    itoa(m_val, m_array, 10);  //doesn't work
                    //sprintf(m_array, "%d", m_val);
                }



                LargeNumber(const LargeNumber& p):m_array(p.m_array)
                { }  //copy constructor


                ~LargeNumber(){
                    delete []m_array;     //for object with new    
                }
               public: //should be private
                int m_val;
                char* m_array;

};
```

Comment: Why do you need to, you already have a constructor that takes an `int`.

Comment: Why do you want to store your number in base-10 as an ASCII string?

Comment: I need to have both of them for my program. I have already one which will take `"string"`. But there is a need for one which will take int value.

Comment: I know that storeing number as a char* is wrong, but I need to manage with that.

Comment: Side note, if default constructor is used the `delete[] m_array` in the destructor will be attempting to deallocate read-only memory.

Comment: Is there a reason `char*` is being used instead of `std::string` for `m_array`?

Comment: You are following a Detonator pattern from resign patterns (http://www.lsd.ic.unicamp.br/~oliva/fun/prog/resign-patterns) with:
1. deleting memory of a literal after creating with default constructor.
2. Not allocating memory for an array you are trying to use (m_array).
3. Sharing pointer in your copy constructor - it will be then double-deleted.
Conclusion - use `std::string` instead of `char *`

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is: don't.  For two reasons:

- As you can see from all the (wrong) other answers, memory management is tricky and bug-prone.
- I can't see how storing your value in base-10, in an ASCII string, could possibly be useful.  (Compared to, say, a base-2<sup>32</sup> representation.)

But if you really must store it this way, you will need to allocate the relevant amount of memory, use `snprintf` to convert (`itoa` is a non-standard function), and remember to free the memory at the correct time(s) (you will **have** to read and understand about the [*Rule of Three*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).

I would strongly recommend using a `std::string` instead of a raw C-style array, because it will at least deal with its own memory management, and you will then be able to populate it with a `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Use `snprintf` (which is C90/C++03).  And use `std::vector<char>` to get the necessary memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yep, I agree with `snprintf`, answer modified.  In terms of storage, I've hinted that there's a host of better idiomatic ways of dealing with this; `vector<char>` is just one possibility.

Comment: Could you write how snprintf function should look in my program ?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `itoa()` needs to be an array in memory large enough to store the null-terminated string. An example:

```
int number = 172839;
char buffer[10];
itoa(number,buffer,10);
```

Comment: So in my case i can't use itoa before my char* m_array doesn't have declared size ?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to actually allocate memory in that buffer before trying to store the string there.

Answer (score 0):

```
LargeNumber(int val):m_val(val)
        {
            std::stringstream stream;
            stream << val;
            m_array = new char[stream.str().size()];
            strcpy(m_array, stream.str().c_str());
        }
```

Comment: No memory allocated for `m_array`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first allocate the array with

```
m_array = new char[20]
```

in constructor before calling iota.
the iota doesnt allocate memory.